# How to import other modules defined in the same Android app project inside Kotlin code?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was trying to understand how to create multiple independent modules inside a project and use them in the main `app` module. I am using android studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1. I have difficulty in importing the module into Kotlin code. Here is the step I followed.

I have created a 'basic activity' project named `MyAppProj`. It created a project with module `app` inside it. (build+run works fine)

Next I added a new module to the project `MyAppProj`. Since I needed to call C++, I created a 'Android native library' module. As per the suggestion from Android Studio, I used `MyAppProj:nativelib` as the module name. I didn't know what that ":" was for. (build+run works fine)

Now I have the following structure:

[image: Project Structure]

█ **Question**: What should I do to use the `NativeLib` class (defined inside `MyAppProj:nativelib` module) inside the `app` module's `MainActivity.kt` file?

All the paths that I tried so far have failed, such as:

```
import com.myhomeorg.myappproj.nativelib
import nativelib
```

Note: I am a beginner in Android development. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should launch a sample code
https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples
The page has a few samples

Answer (score 2):

In order to import it you should add to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":MyAppProj")
}
```

and this also to `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':MyAppProj'
```

And then on Kotlin you can import the classes you need like any other.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on the project, which should expose the JNI bindings:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":MyAppProj")
}
```

But one could as well publish to `mavenLocal()` or a `flatDir` repository.

Comment: Could you also include info on what would the kotlin import statement look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":MyAppProj")
}
```

and then add below code in settings.gradle:

include ':MyAppProj'

in Android studio click on file -> new -> import module -> add library location path (MyAppProj file) -> finish
it will automatically add